# How to write a unit test for a django view?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have problems understanding how the unit tests should be designed for django.

From my understanding testing the whole view in one go seems impossible. We need to distinguish between pre-post and post states of request. But I have no idea how to design this. Is there any real life example?

Looking at the documentation the examples are too simplified and only focused on the model.

```
@login_required
def call_view(request, contact_id):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    if request.POST:        
        form = CallsForm(profile.company, request.POST)           
        if form.is_valid()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/' + contact_id + '/calls/')
    else:        
        form = CallsForm(profile.company, instance=call)              
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form':form}
    return render_to_response('conversation.html', variables)
```

**update:**

trying to make a success test work, but it still fails:

```
def test_contact_view_success(self):
    # same again, but with valid data, then
    self.client.login(username='username1', password='password1')
    response = self.client.post('/contact/add/', {u'last_name': [u'Johnson'], }) 
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/')
```

**error message:**

```
AssertionError: Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)
```

I think this is because the form.is_valid() fails and it doesn't redirect, correct?

Comment: Pro-tip: use [the `render()` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead of manually creating a `RequestContext` and calling `render_to_response()` each time; `return render(request, 'conversation.html', variables)`

Comment: Also, the Django docs [recommend against `if request.POST`, and suggest `if request.method == 'POST'` instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) (sometimes, a `POST` request will have an empty `request.POST`, which tests as false and triggers the wrong branch).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**NB NB!** *This isn't strictly a "unit test"; it's difficult and uncommon to write an independent unit test for Django view code. This is more of an integration test...*

You're right that there are several pathways through your view:

1. `GET` or `POST` by anonymous user (should redirect to login page)
2. `GET` or `POST` by logged-in user with no profile (should raise a `UserProfile.DoesNotExist` exception)
3. `GET` by logged-in user (should show the form)
4. `POST` by logged-in user with blank data (should show form errors)
5. `POST` by logged-in user with invalid data (should show form errors)
6. `POST` by logged-in user with valid data (should redirect)

Testing **1** is really just testing `@login_required`, so you could skip it. I tend to test it anyway (just in case we've forgotten to use that decorator).

I'm not sure the failure case (a 500 error page) in **2** is what you really want. I would work out what you want to happen instead (perhaps [use `get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), or catch the `DoesNotExist` exception and create a new profile that way), or redirect to a page for the user to create a profile.

Depending on how much custom validation you have, **4** may not really need to be tested.

In any case, given all of the above, I would do something like:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestCalls(TestCase):
    def test_call_view_deny_anonymous(self):
        response = self.client.get('/url/to/view', follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/login/')
        response = self.client.post('/url/to/view', follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/login/')

    def test_call_view_load(self):
        self.client.login(username='user', password='test')  # defined in fixture or with factory in setUp()
        response = self.client.get('/url/to/view')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'conversation.html')

    def test_call_view_fail_blank(self):
        self.client.login(username='user', password='test')
        response = self.client.post('/url/to/view', {}) # blank data dictionary
        self.assertFormError(response, 'form', 'some_field', 'This field is required.')
        # etc. ...

    def test_call_view_fail_invalid(self):
        # as above, but with invalid rather than blank data in dictionary

    def test_call_view_success_invalid(self):
        # same again, but with valid data, then
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/contact/1/calls/')
```

Obviously, a drawback here is hard-coded URLs. You could either [use `reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) in your tests or [build requests using `RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory) and call your views as methods (rather than by URL). With the latter method, though, you still need to use hard-coded values or `reverse()` to test redirect targets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Took me a few days to get all these running. Thanks again for your great explanation. The only test I can't seem to run is the last one (test_call_view_success)  Even though I am passing all required fields as post data, it still throws 200 intstead of 302. Hence the test fails.  Its weird how do I test for success then? Please see updated question. Thank you

Comment: You could `print response.context['form'].errors` to see why `form.is_valid()` is returning `False`. If you need further help, please post the code for `CallsForm`.

Comment: With regard to making view tests more like unit tests and less like integration tests, you can make view tests independent of `urls.py` by taking advantage of [SimpleTestCase.urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.urls).  Also, you can make view tests independent of templates by making test templates and overriding [TEMPLATE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs), for example.

Comment: Thanks @supervacuo for this great answer. One question thought: should the forms be tested away from views instead of inside views?

Comment: @David good thought! I usually start with large tests which hit multiple things and try to pare down from there. Ultimately, yes, I think form logic (hopefully mainly validator logic?) should be tested separately; any suggestions on providing dummy form data during the view test?

Comment: @supervacuo. Especially true when you use the same forms in many views :) I didn't dig much more, but [this article](http://tech.novapost.fr/django-unit-test-your-views-en.html) helped me to understand that 'classic' view tests, are not really unit tests :)

Answer (score 9):

Django ships with a test client which can be used to test the full request/response cycle: [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#overview-and-a-quick-example) contain an example of making a get request to a given url and asserting the status code as well as the template context. You would also need a test which does a POST and asserts  a successful redirect as expected.