# Django Unit Testing 'else' statement in a View to achieve coverage

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, code-coverage

I'm running django test coverage for my `interface` app. The view below calls a `WelcomeMessage` model and basically says if there are no messages in that queryset it defaults to the "Welcome.." and if there are more than 1 "active" it will show the most recent one. Basically, how do I test the `else` line, when there there are more than 1 active messages?

I've tried creating two different instances of `WelcomeMessage` with one being more recent, but when I run coverage it still highlights the `else` segment as red.

Running coverage with:
`coverage run --source='.' manage.py test interface`

view:

```
def index(request):

    msg = WelcomeMessage.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-modified_at')
    if len(msg) == 0:
        msg = "Welcome message"
    else:
        msg = msg[0] # -- Need test coverage here --

    context = {'msg': msg}
    return render(request, 'interface/index.html', context)
```

unittest:

```
 def test_indexWelcomeMessage(self):
        welcome1 = WelcomeMessage.objects.create(
            created_at=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
            modified_at=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
            active=True,
            msg="Welcome message"
        )
        welcome2 = WelcomeMessage.objects.create(
            created_at=datetime.now(),
            modified_at=datetime.now(),
            active=True,
            msg="Recent welcome message"
        )
        messages = WelcomeMessage.objects.filter(
            active=True).order_by('-modified_at')

        if len(messages) == 0:
            msg = "testing this message"
        else:
            msg = messages[0]
        recentMsgVal = getattr(welcome2, 'msg')
        msg = messages[0]
        expectedMsgVal = messages.values_list('msg', flat=True).first()
        self.assertNotEqual(len(messages), 0)
        self.assertEqual(recentMsgVal, expectedMsgVal) # These asserts pass, but no coverage.
```

WelcomeMessage model:

```
class WelcomeMessage(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created')
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True, verbose_name="Last change")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    msg = models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name='Message')
```

How do write a test so that it has coverage of the `else` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you are not calling `index()` method directly or indirectly on this test case. To prove that to yourself add a debugger(`ipdb`, `pycharm debugger` - does not matter) or raise some error on that else statement and run tests again. It should run as before.

If you want to write test case take a look at this example this example [How to write a unit test for a django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885211/how-to-write-a-unit-test-for-a-django-view)
Inyour case it should look smth like this:

```
def test_index_welcome_message(self):
    welcome1 = WelcomeMessage.objects.create(
    created_at=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
        modified_at=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
        active=True,
        msg="Welcome message"
    )
    welcome2 = WelcomeMessage.objects.create(
        created_at=datetime.now(),
        modified_at=datetime.now(),
        active=True,
        msg="Recent welcome message"
    )
    messages = WelcomeMessage.objects.filter(
        active=True).order_by('-modified_at')
    # this needed in case route needs auth
    self.client.login(username='user', password='test')
    response = self.client.get('/url/to/index/view')
    assert response == expected_response
```

p.s. that `self.client` is instance of `django.test.Client` but check your project `BaseTestCase`, you might have one already defined.

Comment: Adding the `response = self.client.get(` worked! I had the same client response test code in another method above, I didn't know I needed another statement in the unittest above. Guess I'm learning that's what you need when testing if/else branches. Thanks!